# How do I find a function for a known graph? Is there a reverse grapher?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I'm trying to find functions to describe relationships that are simply described in english or graphically.

For example, for $x \leq 0$, $f(x) = 1$; and as $x$ gets bigger $f(x)$ approaches $0$ ($y=0$ is an asymptote). The graph looks something like this:
[sketch of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ11P.png).

How do I work backwards to turn this into a mathematical function of the form: $$f(x) = something$$

Comment: It's always going to be tricky to do this, because there are an enormous spectrum of functions that fit the above criteria. You're not going to get a step-by-step algorithm that will produce a function fitting criteria like this.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you presumably are offering an analog input, which has a (perhaps large) range of imprecision, while you’re hoping for a precise output. You can not reasonably expect an imprecise input to give you a precise output.

Comment: Suggestion:  graph the function and describe the graph.  But this will likely be inexact.  To be precise you should fit the graph (using an "appropriate" basis set) and construct the function directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can write down all functions which may apply to your problem and then sort them out.

For $x\leq0$ you can simply take $f(x)=1$.

For $x>0$ you can take functions in $\mathcal O\big(\frac1x\big)$ because $\frac1x\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$. In order to make the whole function continuous let‘s take $\frac1{x+1}$.

Putting all together we get
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{for } x<0\\
\frac1{x+1},&\text{for } x\geq0
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: What are these sorts of functions, that are composed of multiple distinct functions over distinct domains, called?

Comment: @Jac They are called piecewise-defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not unique for example your function could be described as $f( x)=1$ for $x<0$ and $f( x)=e^{-x}$. for $x\ge  0$

In general you can approximate your function by collecting data

and pass a polynomial through your data  or using 
Regression analysis and find a good fit for your graph.

It is all approximation of course but your formula is ok for interpolation .